# Amazon Route 53: register domain/hosted zone can't route traffic to a IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

1. I registered a domain with Amazon Route 53.
2. I accidentally deleted the auto-generated NS and SOA records under "Hosted Zone"
3. I manually recreated the NS and SOA records.
4. I add an A record to route to an IP.
5. I can't access the website thru the domain name.

The problem seems the "relation" between the domain name with the hosted zone/records are broken.

What should I do?

Comment: Delete the hosted zone, recreate it, change your domains name servers to the new ones.

Comment: try it few time already, still doesn't work